# wget specify downloaded file name and no other file

Tags: wget

I want to use wget so that my file takes on the name I want. For example, if I do `wget -r http://www.x.com/y/z`, the main file will be named `z`, even though it's actually `index.html`.

I checked the `-O` option of wget, but according to the manual:

```
‘-O file’
‘--output-document=file’
The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file. ...
```

It seems like all the files will be concatenated and written to the file of the desired name. I would like only the main file (and not any file resulting from recursion) to be concatenated. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I would like only the main file to be concatenated."

Comment: Ultimately, the web server is the one who decides what it will send to you depending on the incoming url, so there is no absolute solution to this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Leave out the `-r` if you only want the main file:

```
wget -O customFileName http://www.x.com/y/z
```

`wget` does not support renaming just one file of a recursive download.  Remember that filenames correspond to parts of the URL and renaming the file would break links between files.  You can always either break it in two:

```
wget -O customFileName http://www.x.com/y/z
wget -r http://www.x.com/y/z
```

or just rename the file yourself:

```
wget -r http://www.x.com/y/z
mv z customFileName
```

Comment: @PaulS. I've added some other options.

Answer (score 3):

Try appending a `/` to the end of the URL:

```
$ wget -r http://www.x.com/y/z/
```

This results in an `index.html` file being saved instead of a `z` file

Comment: Okay... but it is possible to choose a file name that I want?

Comment: From `man wget`: --default-page=name: Use name as the default file name when it isn't known (i.e., for URLs that end in a slash), instead of index.html.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to concatenate the file that the server points to and download all the files into one place recursively on the site.

concatenate:

```
wget -qO- http://www.google.com
```

recursive download to one place:

```
wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P ./LOCAL-DIR http://www.google.com
```

Where LOCAL-DIR is the one directory all the directories will be downloaded to.
From this site:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/